# Get the key of a JS Object from the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to get the `key` of a `JS Object` in Typescript from an input value, the problem is that the values are inside an `Array`.

This is what I have seen in the case that the value is not in an array:

```
const exampleObject = {
  key1: 'Geeks',
  key2: 'Javascript'
};

function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  for (var prop in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          if (object[prop] === value)
          return prop;
      }
  }
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(exampleObject,'Geeks')) // key1
```

This is an example of my object that I want to get the key from:

```
const exampleObject = {
  key1: ['Geeks','test1','test2'],
  key2: ['Javascript','test3','test4']
};

function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  for (var prop in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          if (object[prop] === value)
          return prop;
      }
  }
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(exampleObject,'Geeks')) // undefined
```

I need to get the key without using `Array.prototype.includes()`, because typing the resulting variable as `String` gives me an `error` that it may be undefined.

**My problem**: I don't know how to go through the array inside the function to find the value and get the key

**Update**:

What I want is to avoid the possibility of returning an undefined, since the input value will always be inside the object, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Could the string in reality be undefined or is this just a TypeScript Error?

Comment: @SebastianSalletmayer It's a typescript error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single line of code by using 3 JavaScript methods - [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) & [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) **:**

```js
const exampleObject = {
  key1: ['Geeks','test1','test2'],
  key2: ['Javascript','test3','test4']
};

function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  const res = Object.keys(exampleObject).find(key => exampleObject[key].indexOf(value) !== -1);
  return res || '' 
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(exampleObject,'Geeks'))
```

Comment: I haven't used `indexOf()` much, I have a doubt, why when I remove `!== -1` from the code does it return the key `key2`?

Comment: Yes it will return `key2`. For comparison we are using `!== -1` just to check if searched value is there or not. I added the documentation link in the answer. You can have a look.

Comment: I am trying this way of doing it because it is quite short and understandable, but I need to know how to avoid the possibility of returning an undefined, I have updated the question

Comment: If I pass a variable to this function that is not inside the object, it returns an undefined. This will never happen but there is a possibility, so when typing the variable that is going to receive the data as String, it gives me the following error : `Type 'unknown' cannot be assigned to type 'string'`

Comment: So in that case what you can do is .. assigning an empty string to a variable if it is undefined. I updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: @segmet I added this line `return res || ''`. Now if `res` will be undefined then it will return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

@segmet
You can use my code

```js
const exampleObject = {
  key1: ['Geeks', 'test1', 'test2'],
  key2: ['Javascript', 'test3', 'test4']
};
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  var output = "";
  for (var prop in object) {
    // finding and removing element from array
    object[prop].find(i => {
      if (i === value) {
        output = prop;
        return prop;
      }
    })
  }
  return output
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(exampleObject, 'Geeks'))
```

Comment: Need to remove the break statement, the current code won't work when finding the key for "Javascript".

Answer (score 0):

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  const key = Object.entries(object).filter(([key, val]) => val.includes(value));
  return Object.fromEntries(key);
}
```

Try this function instead
You will get the object matching your keys

Comment: This returns an array with the key and value and you're using include() I'm looking for a way to not use it if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and then check for `null`

```js
const getKeyFromValue = (obj:Object, value:string | string[]) => { 
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            if (obj[ key ].includes(value)) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(value)) { 
            if (obj[ key ].every(val => value.includes(val))) {
                return key;
            }
        }
       
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What I want to avoid is using includes(), checking that it is an array to control the return value is bad practice in this case

Comment: Than you can try do it like this: if (object[prop].some(el => el === value))

Answer (score 0):

One more try:

```js
const exampleObject = {
  key1: ['Geeks','test1','test2'],
  key2: ['Javascript','test3','test4']
};

function getKeyByValue(obj, data) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    return (~value.indexOf(data)) ? key : false
  }
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(exampleObject,'Geeks'))
```